# How to open a new console and run a python script

Tags: python, bash, sublimetext2

Here is my problem: When running a python script from command line (bash), I'd like to open a new console window, run my python script and end up in the interactive python shell. Is there an easy way to do this?

Background: Right now, I am exploring sublime text 2 by developing a simple python script together with numpy. When I run build from within sublime, the script is executed but I do not have the possibility to further interact with the result.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using [iPython](http://ipython.org), from there you are able to run scripts, interact with the variables and much more.

You mentioned you use NumPy, iPython is targeted for the scientifical/numerical-analysis users.

If you have some spare time, you should try installing the iPython notebook, really in my humble opinion the best way to interact with python.

[image]

Comment: python -i does the thing i want, but i will have a look into iPython as well. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can open a REPL in the current console with the [`code`](http://docs.python.org/library/code.html) module.

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to create a window appear..?

You can try this:

- you should download pygame as well as your python version

You've to import the pygame & sys for system exit, then import from pygame.locals.
Here's the script

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((x, y)) # use the integer of Width(x) & Height(y) of the window
pygame.display.set_caption('Blank Window')

while True : # game event loop
    for event pygame.event.get(): # we used this, so the window won't 'hang' if we wanna quit the window (event is a variable name so you can named it as you like it)
     if event.type == QUIT:
       pygame.quit()
       sys.exit()
pygame.display.update() # this's for the update of the script
```

This's the far as I know...
^_^ sorry for any mistake I've made.. You should feel free to ask me though..
But I prefer you to ask this question to the expert...
I know someone, please reply me ASAP if you want know more..

Answer (score 0):

If you're using python 3.2 you can use the python debugger. At the beginning of your project, `import pdb`. Then at the point that you want to enter interactive mode, type `pdb.set_trace()`. (You have to put the trace one line above the last line, otherwise the program will finish and restart.) I don't know how to make it automatically enter interactive mode, but when the program gets to the trace the console will enter the debugger. You can then type `interact`, and press Enter, and you will be in interactive mode, with all your variables preserved.

Comment: Why does this require Python 3.2?

Comment: I don't know. Python 2.7 has pdb, but when I tried the above in Python 2.7 it didn't recognise "interact" as valid input.

Answer (score 0):

This was to obvious :) I need to open a new gnome-terminal or the like:

```
gnome-terminal -e "python -i foo.py"
```

the resulting sublime configuration file thus looks like this

```
}
    "cmd": ["gnome-terminal", "-e", "python -i $file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

Hitting Ctrl + B in sublime now opens a new console window, executes my script and leaves me in an interactive python shell.

A little issue remains, this seems not to work with glumpy. Don't know why.